# Sum rows by date range, for a given identifier

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, range

I looked at many posts with similar, but I believe less complex questions, and just cant seem to work out an answer for this.

I have a >1000000 lines of data, for example in this form:

```
date<-c("9/30/2012","10/31/2012","11/30/2012","12/31/2012","1/31/2013","2/28/2013","3/31/2013","10/31/2012","11/30/2012","12/31/2012","1/31/2013","2/28/2013","3/31/2013")
name<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b")
amount<-c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,800,700,600,500)
data<-data.frame(name,date,amount)
View(data)
```

What I need is, for entries of the same name, sum the amount for dates that are in jan-mar, apr-jun, jul-sep, oct-dec in the same year.

This is my ideal output:

```
date2<-c("9/30/2012","12/31/2012","3/31/2013","12/31/2012","3/13/2013")
name2<-c("a","a","a","b","b")
amount2<-c(100,900,1800,2500,1800)
data2<-data.frame(name2,date2,amount2)
View(data2)
```

Will appreciate any input at all, to lead me towards the correct direction.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Using dplyr/zoo**

We can convert the 'date' class from 'character' to 'Date', get the `sum` of 'amount' and `last` value of 'date' grouped by columns 'name' and 'Qtr' (from converting the 'date' to year quarter (`as.yearqtr`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
 data %>%
     mutate(date=as.Date(date, format='%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
     group_by(name, Qtr=as.character(as.yearqtr(date))) %>% 
     summarise(amount= sum(amount), date=last(date))
 #  name     Qtr amount       date
 #1    a 2012 Q3    100 2012-09-30
 #2    a 2012 Q4    900 2012-12-31
 #3    a 2013 Q1   1800 2013-03-31
 #4    b 2012 Q4   2500 2012-12-31
 #5    b 2013 Q1   1800 2013-03-31
```

**NOTE:** Also added @docendo discimus suggestion to use `last` and changing the class of 'date' column. The `Qtr` column is 'character' as the `as.yearqtr` class is unsupported by `dplyr` (from the errors).  The 'Qtr' column was not in the expected dataset 'data2'. So, I guess it doesn't matter whether it is 'character' or 'as.yearqtr'.  If we don't change the 'date' column to 'Date' class, and do the change in the `group_by` step, this will give the same result as the 'data2'.  The extra 'Qtr' column can be deleted.

**2. Without using zoo**

```
 data %>%
     mutate(date1 = as.Date(date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
     group_by(name, Qtr= sprintf('%s %s', format(date1, '%Y'),
                                         quarters(date1))) %>%
     summarise(amount = sum(amount), date=last(date)) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     select(-Qtr) %>% 
     as.data.frame()
 #  name amount       date
 #1    a    100  9/30/2012
 #2    a    900 12/31/2012
 #3    a   1800  3/31/2013
 #4    b   2500 12/31/2012
 #5    b   1800  3/31/2013
```

**NOTE2:** Added a solution without using `as.yearqtr`, kept the same format for 'date' as in the expected output 'data2'

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Thanks, I had some errors while trying to use `as.yearqtr` inside the `dplyr` loop.

Comment: @docendodiscimus  By changing the `as.yearqtr` to `character` class, it now works.

Comment: Thanks! That worked really great. Appreciate all your replies everyone!
One thing though, my output should have around 1/4 of the number of rows as my original data, but now i seem to only have 80K plus rows..

This is what I see on R now:
'Source: local data frame [82,995 x 4]'
does anyone know why that might be the case?

Comment: @rjpjw0 Could you try this on a smaller subset of data to see if the problem persists?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few approaches:

**1) aggregate & zoo**

```
library(zoo)

aggregate(amount ~ name + yearqtr, 
          transform(data, yearqtr = as.yearqtr(date, "%m/%d/%Y")), 
          sum)
```

**2) data.table & zoo**

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

dt <- data.table(data, key = "name,date")
dt[, date := as.yearqtr(date, "%m/%d/%Y")][, list(sum = sum(amount)), by = "name,date"]
```

Note that both these solutions convert the `date` to a real `"yearqtr"` object and not just to a character string.  I haven't benchmarked these but typically data.table is very fast.  You could create the data.table from `data` by reference using `setDT` for every greater performance but might prefer to keep them separate as well so we left them separate here.